# google map map.fitBounds() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps

I have error when I load my page: https://www.cupsubito.it/dove-siamo

I don't kwon because about this error. Thank you very much for helping.

[image]

Thanks for help me!

The code JS is:

let _locations = [];

```
    var elenco;

    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var slider, infowindow = null;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var current = 0;
    var map = 0;


    var icons = {
        //'default': '/assets/img/marker.png'
    };

    function showMap() {
        infowindow.close();
        if (!map.slide) {
            return;
        }
        var next, marker;
        if (_locations.length == 0) {
            return
        } else if (_locations.length == 1) {
            next = 0;
        }
        if (_locations.length > 1) {
            do {
                next = Math.floor(Math.random() * _locations.length);
            } while (next == current)
        }
        current = next;
        marker = _locations[next];
        setInfo(marker);
        //infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }

    function initialize() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.4053848, 12.4276547),
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        map.slide = true;

        //setMarkers(map, _locations);
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "loading..."
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
            infowindow.close();
        });
        slider = window.setTimeout(showMap, 3000);
    }

    function setInfo(marker) {
        var content =
            '<div class="profile-widget" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">' +
            '<div class="doc-img">' +
            '<a href="' + marker.profile_link + '" tabindex="0" target="_blank">' +
            '<img class="img-fluid" alt="' + marker.doc_name + '" src="' + marker.image + '">' +
            '</a>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="pro-content">' +
            '<h4 class="text-center">' +
            '<a href="' + marker.profile_link + '" tabindex="0">' + marker.doc_name + '</a>' +
            '</h4>' +



            '<ul class="available-info pt-5">' +
            '<li><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> ' + marker.address + ' </li>' +

            '</ul>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        infowindow.setContent(content);
    }

    function setMarkers(map, markers) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var item = markers[i];
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                doc_name: item.doc_name,
                address: item.address,
                speciality: item.speciality,

                profile_link: item.profile_link,

                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: icons[item.icons],
                image: item.image
            });

            bounds.extend(marker.position);
            markers[i] = marker;
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                setInfo(this);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
                window.clearTimeout(slider);
            });
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
            if (map.zoom > 16) map.slide = false;
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ markers, map });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        $.ajax({

            url: "?handler=ElencoStrutture",
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: elenco,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success: function (data) {

                //console.error(data.ElencoStrutture);

                _locations = data.ElencoStrutture;

                setMarkers(map, _locations);
                slider = window.setTimeout(showMap, 3000);

                //alert("done ELENCO STRUTTURE");
            }
        });
    });
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, I don't understand why it doesn't always work.
The problem is that it usually works the first time, so I don't understand where I'm wrong on the code side.

The map should display all pointers correctly and instead it sometimes shows me a blank map with this error.

I added part of code where I load setMarkers(map, _locations) for to have more informations.

thank you very much for answers.

I hope I have added useful information to my problem, I don't understand why it sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Where is the function ``setMarkers`` called? To answer your question it would be good to know, if the ``map`` object is created properly...

Comment: "*sometimes works / sometimes doesn't*" - could mean you're running code before it's loaded.  Google maps does a lot of async loading, so you need to ensure all the map code has fully loaded before using it.

Comment: on page load setMarkers(map, _locations); You can see it on code of page, at line 10467. I hope to answer to you @biberman

Comment: @Fabio In which file - or is it an inline script?

Comment: @biberman is all on file of page, on the success of ajax call: success: function (data) {

                //console.error(data.ElencoStrutture);

                _locations = data.ElencoStrutture;

                setMarkers(map, _locations);
                slider = window.setTimeout(showMap, 3000);

                //alert("done ELENCO STRUTTURE");
            }

Comment: I think the problem is, that you ``initialize()`` the map with ``google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`` and do the ajax call with the ``setmarkers()`` function in an separate handler for the ``$('document').ready`` event. So it could help, to call the ``initialize()`` function in the success block of that ajax call before the call of the ``setmarkers()`` function...

Comment: can you give me an example? thank you very much!! @biberman

Comment: ``google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
 $.ajax({
  ...
  success: function (data) {
   initialize();
   _locations = data.ElencoStrutture;
   setMarkers(map, _locations);
  ...
 });
});``

Comment: Or: ``$('document').ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
  ...
  success: function (data) {
   initialize();
   _locations = data.ElencoStrutture;
   setMarkers(map, _locations);
  ...
 });
});``

Comment: But i think, the first could be better...

Comment: It sounds, like you are calling ``setMarkers()`` when the document is loaded, but calling ``initialize()`` when the map is loaded (not sure, if interpreted correctly). But i don't know if the second case is after the document ready or before. Therefor it would be the best, to do both in one event handler...